# Проблема в поиске MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Есть таблица
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

когда провожу поиск то регион игнорируется:

```
SELECT * 
FROM filter 
WHERE 
  typehouse = "Земля" AND typeoffer="Аренда" OR typeoffer="Продам" AND
  region="Омск" AND  price BETWEEN 10000 and 20000
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0,30
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можете обьяснить почему при поиске игнорируется столбец ???

Comment: код должен быть в вопросе. пожалуйста скопируйте запрос и вставьте его в вопрос обрамив тегами кода.

Comment: почему - потому что не стоят скобки ограничивающие `OR`

Comment: Сможешь дать пример как правильно ?

Comment: `(typeoffer="Аренда" OR typeoffer="Продам")` , ответ ниже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас не ограничен логический оператор `OR`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM filter 
WHERE 
  typehouse = "Земля" AND (typeoffer="Аренда" OR typeoffer="Продам") AND
  region="Омск" AND price BETWEEN 10000 and 20000
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0,30
```